# For Loop in Robot Framework is note generating all numbers or strings in a list and gives type error

Tags: robotframework

> ${read}=    Read Csv File   ${readcsv}
>
> @{read}=    Convert To List ${read}
>
> : FOR    ${counter}  IN RANGE    @{read}
>
> Log To Console  ${counter}

It reads the data  [['Ramu Govidan'], ['Ajith'], ['Alagu'], ['Mohana'], ]
20150925 15:51:56.716 :  INFO : @{read} = [ ['Ramu Govidan'] | ['Ajith'] | ['Alagu'] | ['Mohana']  ]
But it gives error Converting argument of FOR IN RANGE failed: TypeError: Expected number, got list..                                                                                                                                                                        For next example for loop

> ${values}=    Get Dictionary Values   ${new dic}
>
> @{values}=    Convert To List ${values}
>
> : FOR  ${counter}  IN RANGE    @{values}
>
> Log  ${counter}
>
> Log   For Loop

For this @{values} = [ 1 | 2 | 3 ]
But for loop generates the output 1, its doesnt generate 2 and 3 . Can any tell the answer both the foor loop.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be using `IN`, not `IN RANGE`. The latter is expecting a number, the former iterates over each item in a list. Since you have a list, you want to use `IN`:

```
| | :FOR | ${item} | IN | @{values}
```

If you actually want a number rather than the item, you can use `IN RANGE` on the length of the items:

```
| | ${len}= | get length | ${values}
| | :FOR | ${count} | IN RANGE | ${len}
```

From the robot framework user guide, section [Normal For Loops](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#normal-for-loop) (emphasis mine):

> **In a normal for loop, one variable is assigned from a list of values**,
>   one value per iteration. The syntax starts with :FOR, where colon is
>   required to separate the syntax from normal keywords. The next cell
>   contains the loop variable, **the subsequent cell must have IN, and the
>   final cells contain values over which to iterate.** These values can
>   contain variables, including list variables.

Here's an excerpt from the user guide, in the section [For-In-Range Loop](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#for-in-range-loop) (emphasis mine):

> Similarly as other for loops, the for-in-range loop starts with :FOR
>   and the loop variable is in the next cell. **In this format there can be
>   only one loop variable and it contains the current loop index. The
>   next cell must contain IN RANGE and the subsequent cells loop limits.**